# How to Increment number using the current date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a `StaffLeave` table in SQL Server with the following columns: `DateStarted`, `DaysTaken`, `DaysOnLeave` and `LeaveStatus`.
Once the staff is on leave the current date should keep counting days on leave into  column DaysOnLeave and when `DaysTaken==DaysOnLeave` the leave status should changed.

This what i've done so far, I read the `DateStarted` from the database using `ExecuteReader` and store the date into a variable. I then compare the current date with it. If the current date is greater then I increment `DaysOnLeave` by one.

I am having this problem when checking the second,third,forth day and so on where the current date will be greater by 2,3,4  days and so on.

Comment: Can you show us your code please, what you have so far.

Comment: already answered thanks

Comment: If you do not want answer further more then you can close the tread and accept the correct answer.

Comment: and how do i do that

Comment: @muhdamean next to the answer you want, click on the check mark to set the answer as accepted.

Comment: just did that, most appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use:

```
var daysOnLeave = (DateTime.Now -DateStarted).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeNow = DateTime.Now;

var holidays = (timeNow - DateStarted).TotalDays;
```

Use the holidays (or in your case, DaysOnLeave) and increment `DaysOnLeave++;`